# How to write a CWL entry for \caption's \captionof command?

Tags: texstudio

I'm using the `caption` package in TexStudio, and it correctly highlights the various parts of the `\caption` command, but it does no such thing for the `\captionof` command. So I'm trying to write a custom `.cwl` for `\captionof`. This command takes three fields:

`\captionof{floattype}[tocentry]{caption}`

So a typical usage would be something like this:

`\captionof{figure}[A Roman banquet]{A Roman banquet as depicted by John the Painter. Note the lack of spices and the limited selection of beverages.}`

The `floattype` field can be at least `figure` or `table`. I assume there are more possibilities, but I haven't had the need for them. The `tocentry`field is a short caption for the TOC, and the `caption` field is a full caption. Both are text fields, obviously.

With the `\caption` command, Tex Studio highlights the `caption` field according to its configuration, making it easy to find, and allowing it to be spell checked.

So I would like to do the same with the `.cwl` entry for `\captionof`. I've tried `\captionof#S`, copying the autogenerated `.cwl` entry for `\caption` in `caption3.cwl`, but it does nothing. I've tried `\captionof{floattype}[short]{title}` following `latex-document.cwl`'s entry for `\caption`, but this didn't work, either. I've also tried to define the different fields following [the manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION), and I came up with `\captionof{floattype}[TOCentry%text]{caption%text}` and `captionof{floattype}[TOCentry%text]{caption%title}`, but these also do nothing.

Could anyone give me a hand crafting a proper `.cwl` entry for `\captionof`?

I'm using TexStudio 4.2.3 with TexLive 2021. TexStudio detects my custom `.cwl` file, and I've selected it to autoload in the configuration.

EDIT: In the screenshot is the result of implementing the suggestion to add `\captionof{float type}[list entry%text]{heading%title}` to custom .cwl file. "This is a long caption" should be highlighted in purple, but is not.

[image: Result after implementing suggestion to add \captionof{float type}[list entry%text]{heading%title} to custom .cwl file. "This is a long caption" should be highlighted in purple, but is not.]

Comment: What kind of highlighting are you looking for? The built-in file caption.cwl already has listing for \captionof (see here https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/completion/caption.cwl).

Comment: @mbert I'm looking to have the second and third fields of \captionof highlighted just as they are with the \caption command. The caption.cwl file you mentioned is already recognized and loaded by TexStudio, but it doesn't cause any highlighting to occur. I added the three \captionof lines it contains to my custom cwl file, and this also does nothing.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something the only difference between `\caption` and `\captionof` highlighting is that the TOCentry argument is spellchecked in the former but not the latter (the second braced arg of `\captionof` should still be spellchecked). If that's what you want then you can add `\captionof{float type}[list entry%text]{heading%text}` to your custom cwl.

Comment: @mbert The %text suggestion got spell checking working. However, I've replaced `heading%text` with `heading%title` in order to get this field highlighted just like section names, and nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: texstudio's completer is reading multiple lines defining the highlighting and has to pick one. Apparently `%text` has higher priority than `%title`. If you want this then copy caption.cwl, change the \captionof lines to have `%title`, and place it in the `.../texstudio/completion/user` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\captionof{float type}[list entry%text]{heading%text}` to your custom cwl. This will enable spellchecking in the "list entry" argument.

Comment: Your suggestion contained the proper code. I changed `heading%text`to `heading%title` to get the highlighting I wanted. To get it to actually work, I went into TexStudio's configuration, deactivated the built-in `caption.cwl` in the Completion section, and activated my own version of this file, which included your suggestion. This won't work with `custom.cwl` because it will exclude all of the `caption.cwl` file's contents except the suggested change. Cheers!